# Find if any value from a range is in an array

Tags: excel

I want a formula that will look at a (one-wide) array of cells, and return TRUE if any of those cells take a value between 22 and 30, and FALSE otherwise. Is there an elegant way to do this, or should I just search for every value individually, and shove them inside an OR?

The only way I can think of to do it is

```
=NOT(AND(ISNA(VLOOKUP(22,ArrayAddress,1)),ISNA(VLOOKUP(23,ArrayAddress,1)),ISNA(VLOOKUP(24,ArrayAddress,1))...))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ArrayAddress>=22)*(ArrayAddress<=30))>0
```

or

```
=COUNTIFS(ArrayAddress,">=22",ArrayAddress,"<=30")>0
```

Comment: ...I can't believe I didn't think to use COUNTIF. Thanks!